# MYSQL REGEXP search in JSON string

Tags: mysql, regex, json

I'm a beginner in regexp and i try to search in json formatted text, but i cannot make it work right:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tag, body FROM pages 
WHERE (body REGEXP BINARY '"listeListeOuiNon":".*1.*"')
```

It shows me as results text with

`"listeListeOuiNon":"1"` and

`"listeListeOuiNon":"1,2"` and

`"listeListeOuiNon":"0,1"` `as expected`,

but also `"listeListeOuiNon":"2" (not expected)`

Any idea?
Maybe it's because it's greedy, but i'm not sure...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a word of caution, MySQL REGEX is a *very* expensive operation.  It's often faster to break what you can into several LIKE statements if you can swing it.

Also, is this a common query or will the matching text change often?

Comment: yes i know about like being faster, but in fact matching text is changing and trying it with LIKE '"listeListeOuiNon":"%1%"' is not better..

Comment: Can you give us an example row where "listeListeOuiNon":"2" was matched?

Comment: yes for example : SELECT '"listeListeOuiNon":"2", "listeToto":"1"' REGEXP BINARY '"listeListeOuiNon":".*1.*"'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to replace the two `.*` with `[^"]*`... That'll however only be sufficient if your `listeListeOuiNon` cannot contain litteral `"`s, or you'd have to also handle the escape sequence. Basically with the `.` you'll match any JSON string that has a `1` "after" `"listListOuiNon":"`, even if it's in another field, and yes, that's because it's greedy.

Comment: waouw! it seems to work!! SELECT '"listeListeOuiNon":"2", "listeToto":"1"' REGEXP BINARY '"listeListeOuiNon":"[^"]*1[^"]*"' is egal to 0! merci beaucoup!

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's quite easy to debug:

`SELECT '"listeListeOuiNon":"2"' REGEXP BINARY '"listeListeOuiNon":".*1.*"'`

returns 0

`SELECT '"listeListeOuiNon":"1"' REGEXP BINARY '"listeListeOuiNon":".*1.*"'`

returns 1

`SELECT '"listeListeOuiNon":"1,2"' REGEXP BINARY '"listeListeOuiNon":".*1.*"'`

returns 1

So something is not right at your side... because it just could not return rows where body equals `"listeListeOuiNon":"2"`. But it is possible, that body has several of these statements, something like:

body => '"listeListeOuiNon":"1,2", "listeListeOuiNon":"2"'

So you have to modify your regexp:

`'^"listeListeOuiNon":".*1.*"$'`

Well, then you have to modify your query:

`SELECT DISTINCT tag, body FROM pages 
WHERE (body REGEXP BINARY '"listeListeOuiNon":".*1.*"') AND NOT (body REGEXP BINARY '"listeListeOuiNon":"2"')`

Comment: thanks Jauzsika, but in fact i have complicated data, like : {"bf_titre":"Veille partage","listeListeLogiciel":"BAZ","listeListeEtatDuBug":"CONF","listeListeBugs":"USER","listeListeOuiNon":"2","bf_sauveur":"Florian","id_typeannonce":"31","createur":"Anonyme","categorie_fiche":"Maintenance du site","date_creation_fiche":"2011-08-30 14:20:09","date_debut_validite_fiche":"2011-08-30","date_fin_validite_fiche":"0000-00-00","statut_fiche":"1","id_fiche":"VeillePartagee"}   <-- and for this it doesn't work..

Answer (score 1):

Returns 0.

[image]

Comment: my problem is that have have more in my json text.. : SELECT '"listeListeOuiNon":"2", "listeToto":"1"' REGEXP BINARY '"listeListeOuiNon":".*1.*"'